# Kullback-Leibler Divergence to compare two sample distributions

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler

I have an algorithm to which I supply a specific input. The algorithm is deterministic, and will always yield the same result.

I also have a random algorithm that uses random choices to speed up execution. It might compute a different result given the same input, but will in general not. If it computes a different result, it is not very different from the deterministic result.

I have 200 unique inputs to these algorithms, and I would like to say something about the distribution of the results. I claim that the distribution of results are the same, with the deterministic algorithm acting as ground truth.

Here is a plot of the results from the deterministic algorithm:
[image]

and here is a plot of the results from the random algorithm when I use e.g. 5 cores

[image]

The distribution appear to be skew-normal. I can visually convince myself that they should draw results from the same distribution (up to some small variance), but I would like to test this. **I read about the Kullback-Leibler Divergence online, and saw that it computes a numerical measure of how different one distribution is from another.** I get a very low number when I shove my data into this algorithm. However, **is it OK to use my ground-truth data as the baseline distribution like this?** I don't have the actual distribution, I just have data that I know are drawn from it. Which number would be low enough that I can say that the algorithm draws results from the same distribution?

Comment: You seem to have pairwise data (maybe add tag [tag:paired-data]), and that pairing should be used in the comparison?